# How to use multiple ssh keys for multiple gitlab accounts with the same host

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I want to use 2 accounts in [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) website, every account with a different ssh key

I generated the keys successfully and add them in `~/.ssh`  folder
I created `~/.ssh/config` file and use one of them , it's works good
I can also make swapping between the two keys by editing the `~/.ssh/config` file

**The problem is :** I want to use them in the same time , but all the  tutorials i found taking about different hosts :/

actually my two accounts are in the same host

how can i edit the `~/.ssh/config` file to accept two accounts for the same host

**Note:**  I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14888056/3185456) but i can't get help from it

My two accounts are `username1` and `username2`
repo URL looks like : [git@gitlab.com:username1/test-project.git](http://git@gitlab.com:username1/test-project.git)

My current `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host gitlab.com-username1
  HostName gitlab.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host gitlab.com-username2
  HostName gitlab.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_username2
```

**Update 1:**

1) When I use one key in the `~/.ssh/config` file , everything works perfect (but it's very boring to update it every time i want to change the user i use)

2) When i use this lines
`ssh -T git@gitlab.com-username1
ssh -T git@gitlab.com-username2`
its works good and return a welcoming message

From 1) and 2) , i think the problem is definitely from the `~/.ssh/config` file , specifically in `Host` variable

**Update 2: (the solving)** 
the solving was to edit the `.git/config` file from 
`[remote "origin"]
  url = git@gitlab.com:username1/test-project.git` 
to 
`[remote "origin"]
  url = git@gitlab.com-username1:username1/test-project.git`

and do the same for the `username2`

Comment: I read it , i's talking about different accounts , in my case i'm want to do that in the same host :/

Comment: "*I want to use 2 accounts in Gitlab website*"???  The duplicate is using the same host (you only need to substitute github with gitlab. There is only on github.

Comment: it's use `github.com` and `ac2.github.com`
but in my case the same are `gitlab.com` without sub-domain

Comment: It is only alias to github.com as defined in the `~/.ssh/config`. There is no `ac2.github.com`

Comment: okay but in gitlab it's different :/  
anyway can you help me how to do it with gitlab ?

Comment: @OsamaMohamed it's not different, it's exactly the same, and that answer is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @hobbs  but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Only because you're not following the instructions.

Comment: @hobbs i followed it , it's just a simple edits why i maybe don't make it ? :/

Comment: On Mac OS remember to add keys to the keychain: `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa_username2`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have got complete `ssh` configuration. First of all, check if it works:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com-username1
ssh -T git@gitlab.com-username2
```

should succeed in both cases. If not, the keys are not set up correctly. Verify that the keys are on gitlab for respective users.

If it works, move on to your git repository and open `.git/config`. It will have some part like:

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = git@gitlab.com:username1/test-project.git
```

Replace it with

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = git@gitlab.com-username2:username1/test-project.git
```

(or `username1` if you want to connect using this username). Then it should allow you to push.

Comment: the first two lines returns `GitLab: Disallowed command` and  somethims `ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com-username1: Name or service not known`
the difference happens when i edit the `~/.ssh/config` file 
but anyway the keys is okay , because when i use one key in `~/.ssh/config` like 
`Host    gitlab.com
 HostName gitlab.com
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
the code works good :/ and push the commits to gitlab 
so i think that the problem is in the config file :/ 

`

Comment: Maybe without the `verify`. But yes, it looks ok. So fix the config file. Or is there still something unclear?

Comment: yes how can i fix the config :/ , i'll try it without verify

Comment: okay it's works without a verify 
returns  `Welcome to GitLab, username1` and `Welcome to GitLab, username2`

Comment: but it doesn't make the push it's returns this message `GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
`
this message appers only if i use two keys in the `~/.ssh/config` file , but if i use one key in the `~/.ssh/config` file the push command works successfully

Comment: Update the question with related lines from your `.git/config` and what you changed.

Comment: it's works , the solving was to edit the `.git/config` file from `[remote "origin"]
  url = git@gitlab.com:username1/test-project.git` to `[remote "origin"]
  url = git@gitlab.com-username1:username1/test-project.git`

Comment: Thanks a lot , i'm very happy ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Use the exact `~/.ssh/config` from above and update the URLs you use with git to `git@gitlab.com-username1:username1/test-project.git` for the first user and `git@gitlab.com-username2:username2/test-project.git` for the second one (e.g., `git clone git@gitlab.com-username1:username1/test-project.git`).

SSH will look up the `gitlab.com-username1` alias in `~/.ssh/config` and will use the right host name and SSH key file.

Another way would be to just use one user for pushing/pulling and grant the required rights to this one user.

Comment: `  Host git@gitlab.com:username1/test-project.git
    HostName gitlab.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

  Host git@gitlab.com:username1/test-project.git
    HostName gitlab.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_username2`

Comment: i update it i this way but nothing happen , also should i specific every repo in config file ? is there is a way to set the username only :/

Comment: Use the exact .ssh/confit file from your question but use the mentioned urns in your git commands.

Comment: Problem solved now?

Comment: No , it didn't :/
the thing you said i'm already did it and it doesn't work so i write this question

Comment: The comments you posted show that you did it wrong. I updated my answer. Don't update the `.ssh/config` file, use the one you posted in your question. Then for all git opertions don't use `gitlab.com` alone but the defined alias which is the `Host` line in `.ssh/config`. Please add how call git as a comment, I suppose the error lies there.

Comment: ` Host gitlab.com-username1/test-project.git HostName gitlab.com User git IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa Host gitlab.com-username2/test-project.git HostName gitlab.com User git IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_username2`

Comment: i set the remote as git@gitlab.com:username1/test-project.git for username1 project
and git@gitlab.com:username2/test-project.git for the usenamw2 project

Comment: You changed the host line in ,ssh/config which is wrong! It must not include the path. And you need to update the git remote url to the just defined alias. Please re-read my answer.

Comment: So, any news? Working now?

Comment: Host  gitlab.com-username1
 HostName gitlab.com
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host    gitlab.com-username2
 HostName gitlab.com
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_username2

Comment: I did that but nothing new :/

Comment: ok .ssh/config seems to be right. Have you tried cloning or updating the remotes?

Comment: i set the remote by git commands 
then i commit some changes , but i can't push them because of the ssh key :/